# Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated on Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am in L4, here is my app.php

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => 'http://1.1.1.1/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => 'rO9cCeyugcXru0VvBQ7mkP4zLLZceVgp',

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => array(

        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\CommandsServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\MigrationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\SeedServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',
        'Sebklaus\Profiler\Providers\ProfilerServiceProvider'

    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Service Provider Manifest
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service provider manifest is used by Laravel to lazy load service
    | providers which are not needed for each request, as well to keep a
    | list of all of the services. Here, you may set its storage spot.
    |
    */

    'manifest' => storage_path().'/meta',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => array(

        'App'               => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
        'Artisan'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
        'Auth'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
        'Blade'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
        'Cache'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
        'ClassLoader'       => 'Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader',
        'Config'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
        'Controller'        => 'Illuminate\Routing\Controller',
        'Cookie'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
        'Crypt'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
        'DB'                => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
        'Eloquent'          => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
        'Event'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
        'File'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
        'Form'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Form',
        'Hash'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
        'HTML'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\HTML',
        'Input'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
        'Lang'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
        'Log'               => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
        'Mail'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
        'Paginator'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator',
        'Password'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
        'Queue'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
        'Redirect'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
        'Redis'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
        'Request'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
        'Response'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
        'Route'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
        'Schema'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
        'Seeder'            => 'Illuminate\Database\Seeder',
        'Session'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
        'SoftDeletingTrait' => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait',
        'SSH'               => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\SSH',
        'Str'               => 'Illuminate\Support\Str',
        'URL'               => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
        'Validator'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
        'View'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',
        'Carbon'            => 'Carbon\Carbon',

    ),

);
```

I kept gettig

> Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated

How can I prevent that ?

Comment: Upgrade to Laravel 5?

Comment: The site is already deployed and live running on 4.2. If I have to upgrade what is the quickiest way to do without breaking anything ?

Comment: I'm sure there is web documentation that will answer your comment, @ihue

Comment: @ihue Laravel's documentation includes detailed upgrade notes for each version. There's also a paid automated tool: https://laravelshift.com/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use PHP 7 instead of PHP 7.1. Or you can upgrade to Laravel 5 if it's possible. If not, add this to the beginning of the `config/app.php`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

It looks dirty, but I'm afraid there is no a better way to avoid the error at the moment.

Comment: @ihue Yes, but it's just masking the eventual problem. These deprecated functions **will** go away at some point.

Comment: For the record, I also get this in Laravel 5.4 when using PHP 7.1, so a straight upgrade to L5 won't necessarily fix things. Hopefully Laravel 5.5 has addressed the core issue.

Comment: Might suggest this instead:`error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_DEPRECATED);` in case you have other error settings and don't want E_ALL.