# 404 error after updating PHP on Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I have a website made on Laravel 5.3 that was working fine under PHP 7.0

I found some errors on the site and after looking online for a solution, the unanimous cause was that the laravel and php versions are not compatible.

I then went to check my composer.json file and saw that the minimum version of php needed is 7.1 and up.

I told my hosting company to update PHP to 7.2 on my staging server and now when I try to access it, I get an error:

> Oups ! Page not found !
>   (Error 404)

Error. Any idea if there's anything I need to do?

My Error Log:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a89f6b95d3ab9bf1b4a8f231250de96220190730104107/cef049

Comment: You need to add some more information. Logs, etc so we can see what laravel is doing.

Comment: laravel 5.3 doesnt require php 7^. it works fine on php 5.6 but since you updated your PHP, do the same with laravel and update it. you can follow these guides for existing projects. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#upgrade-5.4.0 https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade

Comment: @LLJ97 I just added the error log

Comment: You have to check the permissions of your application. Laravel tried to open a file in a folder without permission. If you're on linux you have to use `chmod` to give them.

Comment: After I changed "laravel/framework" to  "5.7.*" to go along with the php update.

Comment: I stopped getting the 404 error but now im getting these errors: http://az.kiriarabia.com/ar

Comment: @LLJ97 if you can, please check the page I mentioned, its a staging server.

Comment: `mcrypt` is deprecated with php 7.1 and removed with php 7.2. It is possible that you have set `rijndael-128` as your cipher in `config/app.php`. If so change it to `AES-CBC-256`

Comment: It was set to MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, I now changed it to 'cipher' => AES-CBC-256, but the issue is still there

Comment: Please refer to this question, which is exactly your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41031076/php7-1-and-laravel-5-3-function-mcrypt-get-iv-size-is-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

From the error log, by default the storage folder has  root permission, change the ownership of the storage folder to apache, as the apache writes logs on the storage folder